# Active directory B2C Authorization on Android

Tags: android, authorization, azure-ad-b2c, bearer-token, azure-ad-msal

I've successfully signed in using "Azure AD B2C" on my android app. But I am not able access my  asp.net core web api using the bearer token. The api is returning 401 "Unauthorized error".

I am able to  access the same api from swagger UI and Postman.

I tried to access the api  from postman using bearer token  received on my mobile. The api returned with the 
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found". 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you create Resource and Client apps as described from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-api.  To access Web API from your mobile app token, you should grant the permission.

Comment: Yes. PublicClientApp.Acquiretoken () returned  success with a access token.  unfortunately retrofit api call  returned "401 unauthorized error"

Comment: It will throw error if you miss granting user impersonation on resource app to client app